# ParsleyJS Custom validator skips validation with no error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, parsley.js

I'm attempting to use ParsleyJS to validate my fields, and I've written a custom validator that will hopefully in the future allow me to check if a field is either blank or not equal to another field, but it simple never seems to be called. I previously attempted to combine the two validators and the notblank validator didn't get called, so I wrote this. Here is my custom validator and a link to a jsfiddle you can play with for the issue. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance for any help!

```
$(function () {
    $('#form').parsley({
        validators: {
            notblankequalto: function (val, notblankequalto) {
                return {
                    validate: function () {
                        alert('hi');
                        return false;
                    },
                        'priority': 2
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            notblankequalto: "This value should be equal to the value above it"
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JmPfQ/7/

Comment: Why do you need a custom validator for this? Why not use the built-in `parsley-equalto` validator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue ended up being less than obvious and I'm not entirely sure WHY it was presenting itself. When I changed the "optional" class to "required" it began working again. Then I could use the parsley-equalto as well as parsley-notblank.

Answer (score 1):

The form id should be `form`, not `#form`.

See fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/JmPfQ/9/

Comment: #form should be alright since I had the ID on the form. I found the issue though and posted it below. Thank you for your help!